# Any examples of remarried widows (punarbhū) in Hindu scripture?

Tags: vedas, puranas, marriage, women, atharva-veda

[Here](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/monier/serveimg.pl?file=/scans/MWScan/MWScanjpg/mw0633-putraphalabhaktR.jpg) are the dictionary meanings of the word पुनर्भू (punarbhū):

> mfn. being renewed, restored to life or youth RV. AV.
>
> **f. a virgin widow re-married AV.** &c
>
> f. re-existence W.

I'm interested in the second meaning of the word sourced from Atharvaveda. In what context was it used in AV?

Are there any examples of widow remarriages (virgin or not) in Hindu scriptures?

Comment: I'm certain cases, to avoid grammar mistakes, that has to be done

Comment: The [Nala-Damayanti episode](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03070.htm) of Vana Parva of MBH seems to suggest that it was possible but [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12526/4133) post seems to suggest otherwise. It could be that there should be no 'Brahma Vivaha' but a svayamvara could be possible.

Comment: @user1952500 - I think in nala-damyanti episode , Damyanti was not remarrying because she was a widow . She was doing so because it was permitted under Manusmriti 9:76 - "If the husband went abroad for some sacred duty, he should be awaited for eight years; if for learning, or for fame, six years; but three years, if for pleasure"